# Unity3d: Grass on iOS is missing

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine

I have a grass on terrain. In unity editor, in "edit" - "graphic emulation" there is opengl 1.1 and opengl 2.0 options. when I set it to 2.0, grass show fine. but wen I set to opengl es 1.1, grass disappeares. That is OK. But now, I'm trying to build it for my iPad: In player settings i'm setting armv7 platform, iPad only. And I cant see grass on my iPad. Am I doing anything wrong? All I need is to display grass on iPad: no metter opengl version. From xCode logs: "Version: OpenGL ES 2.0 IMGSGX543-63.24", so, openGL version IS 2.0. I guess, it's all about some unity settings stuff, but where?

Comment: If any additional information requaired, please, let me know.

Comment: What shader are you using to draw the grass material?

Comment: I guess it's default shader. I did this: Terrain -> create Terrain. then, in Hierarchy, clicked in terrain,  under Terrain Script choosed grass, added texture and planted some grass. No material choosing, no shader coosind. Only texture.

Comment: The default shader for a new material is Diffuse. Try using one of the Mobile group of shaders. They're a set of shaders optimised for platforms like iOS and Android. If they're not appearing in your list of shaders, open Build Settings from the File menu, select the iOS platform and click Switch Platform.

Comment: Thanks, but where can I set shaders for grass?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it: I'll try to find trrain by tag, get acces to it's gameObject, then, to material: "material.shader = Shader.Find("mobile/***");" I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: Just set the material shader to Mobile/Diffuse for now and see if it still appears on the iPad. The problem might ultimately be elsewhere though.

Comment: there is no material settings for terrain/grass. You can set only texture... And one more thing: I just creater another scene, and planted grass there. on iPad, there is no grass in first scene, but it IS in second. That confuses me a little. May be there is some option, wich turns off grass in some cases?

Comment: I still cant reach grass's material.

Comment: I think you really badly need to read up on what Materials, Textures and Shaders are. It seems you're very uncertain on the definition of what they are.
[link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Materials.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remaded this scene and grass returned to it's place.